# RIP Christopher Plummer

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Actor Christopher Plummer died on February 5 2021 ([BBC article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-55962062)). He is probably better known for non sci-fi roles, but General Chang was one of the most memorable Star Trek bad guys.

[image: General Chang]

Comment: Christopher Plummer finishes climbing every mountain.

Comment: "I can see you, Kirk.  Can you see me?"

Answer (score 10):

Any actor who had as many film and television appearances as Christopher Plummer would naturally have some science fiction and fantasy appearances mixed in.  Besides Plummer's chilling General Chang ("In space, all warriors are cold warriors"), I remember him particularly for his role as the virologist (and Brad Pitt's father) in *Twelve Monkeys*.  Plummer gives a very grounded performance, and serves as a foil for the multiple over-the-top lunatic characters.

Comment: "Video unavailable
This video contains content from Tele München Fernseh GmbH + Co. Produktionsgesellschaft VOD, who has blocked it in your country on copyright grounds." *Sigh*.